# Validity of an unusual limit?

Tags: limits

I have a question about the validity of a limit.

**Definitions**

Let $N$ denote a sequence of positive integers $n_1,n_2,n_3,…$  and $N_k$ denote the k-th initial sequence of $N$ namely $n_1, n_2,n_3 … n_k$. Let $f(x,N_k)$ be a map $R$ x  $Z^k \mapsto  R$ which is continuous in $x$ and each member of $N_k$ separately.  $R$ is the set of Real Numbers and $Z$ the set of positive integers. Finally let the sequence $x_1, x_2, x_3 … $ in $R$ be defined by the equations $f(x_k, N_k) = 0$ for $k = 1,2,3,…$

**My Question**

I want to impose the condition $Lx_k = 0$ and find how this constrains the sequence $N$. The $L$ means the limit as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

My first thought was:

$[L (f(x_k, N_k) = 0)] \Rightarrow  [Lf(x_k, N_k) = L0]  \Rightarrow  [f(Lx_k, LN_k) = 0] \Rightarrow  [f(0,N) = 0]$

but I am unsure about applying $L$ to $N_k$ to make the second implication. Although $f(x_k, N_k)$ is continuous in each member of $N_k$ separately it seems the second implication is treating  $f(x_k, N_k)$ as if it were continuous in the sequence $N_k$ as a single entity?

Any advice, opinions, or direction to references would be appreciated.

**Response to comments from Crostul**

Thanks for pointing out three problems with my question.

The problems with the domain of $f$ (Problem 1) and the uniqueness of $x_k$ (Problem 3) were oversights. I believe the failure to specify the topology (Problem 2) is the source of my confusion.

The domain of $f$ is $R$ x $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty Z^k$ and not $R$ x  $Z^k$ as originally stated in my question. The first input to $f$ is a Real number and the second input is any sequence (finite or infinite) in Z.

The definition in my question of $x_k$ as the solution of $f(x_k, N_k) = 0$ should have said that $f$ has the property that $x_k$  is unique for a particular $N_k$.

I think my question can perhaps be reduced to asking is there a topology X on $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty Z^k$ for which $Lf(x_k, N_k) = f(Lx_k, L_1N_k)$ where $L$ is the limit as $k\rightarrow\infty$ in ($R$ + topology of open intervals defined by the Euclidean metric) and $L_1$ is the limit as $N_k\rightarrow N$  in ($\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty Z^k$ + topology X).

Comment: There are some problems here: 1. the domain of $f$ is not specified (is it $\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^2$, or maybe $\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^5$? or maybe it is the union $\bigcup_k \Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^k$?). 2. Even if it were specified, it is not clear what is the topology of the domain of $f$ ($f$ is continuous, but what is the topology of its domain?). 3. the equation $f(x_k, N_k)=0$ may define more than one value for $x_k$, so that $x_k$ is not well defined.

Comment: My comment is meaningful, since you are using the theorem $$\lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_k , N_k) = f( \lim_k x_k , `` \lim_k N_k \mbox{''}) $$ if you don't specify the domain of $f$ and its topology, your question doesn't make much sense.